# merge replication too big

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication, sql-server-compact

I have multiple handhelds which sync their data via merge replication. From time to time, new core data is imported on the server-database.

For various reasons I keep the old data in the databse and set a flag deactivated = 1.

In a filter I only download rows where deactivated = 0.

The core-data I'm talking about are 6 tables. Each has hundreds of thousands of rows. About 30,000 rows are sent to the handhelds during syncing.

The .OUT-File in the MS SQL CE-folder on the server has about 10 MB (!).

On syncining via gprs I receive this error

> SQL CE error 28562 - Failed to create the Delete message to send to the Server.

Any ideas how to handle this problem?

Mobile DB: SQL Server CE 3.1 SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Do you really need all this data on the device?

Comment: Well I don't know which data i need excatcly, but it can be all of the data in this pool. And it has to work also without internet-connection, that's the reason why I use replication.